# Styling <select> Element with CSS

Tags: css, html-select

I have seen many questions and answers about styling the selection menus in CSS, but I am trying to figure out if it is possible to style the menu itself (the part that appears after click). Also, is it possible to change this menu only without changing the appearance of the select element itself? I would like to change the background color of the menu while keeping the other part the same. I have been Googling this question for awhile, and I've not been able to find any answers. Perhaps I've been searching for the wrong thing...

Comment: No, it is not possible to style the select element itself beyond some basic things like font-size and padding. All of the other "stylized" selects out there are javascript plugins that essentially replace the the select input with divs or ULs .

Comment: Oh, ok I see. Thank you for your response. Would you happen to know any decent examples to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Take this with a grain of salt, as this is purely my opinion, but I use this plugin frequently when working with boostrap projects. https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

Comment: Alright, I'll see if I can use this one. I really appreciate your help, thanks again!